# Which camera API to use for android?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I have come across two ways for custom camera implementation in android. First way is to use the deprecated camera 1 api second is to use the latest updated camera 2 api which does not seem to have a back port for devices below api 21 (Lolipop). My application supports API 18 minimum. Is there any way of doing it without using both api's and providing version checks.

Comment: Even though camera 1 api is deprecated, it's fully functional and a lot of apps use it. Just ignore the warnings of Android Studio, or increase your api level to 21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use below custom camera api for your requirement.

gradle file:

```
compile 'com.otaliastudios:cameraview:1.4.1'
```

custom camera view set like:

```
  <com.otaliastudios.cameraview.CameraView
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

for full support you can use below link:

[**https://github.com/hyl87/CameraView-1**](https://github.com/hyl87/CameraView-1)

i hope it will help you

Comment: the link to github is not found.

Comment: @maxwellnewage At present, link not available but you can try to search "CameraView" SDK for android in web. May be you will able to find other link for same..!